# Tallying a list of a list and associating it with another list

Tags: python

I will try and explain my situation to the best of my ability.

I have one list which contains names

```
 name_list = ["Bob" , "Henry" , "Jeff" , "Harry"]
```

and another list which contains numbers

```
number_list = ["1,4,2,3" , "4,3,1,2" , "3,2,4,1" , "1,2,3,4" , "4,3,2,1" , "1,2,4,3"]
```

I am struggling to come up with a code which will create a tally of sorts which will associate each name with its corresponding position in name_list

ie.

```
 "result" = Bob  - 1:3 , 2:0 , 3:1 , 4:2
            Henry- 1:0 , 2:3 , 3:2 , 4:1
            Jeff - 1:1 , 2:2 , 3:1 , 4:2
            Harry- 1:2 , 2:1 , 3:2 , 4:1
```

Is this actually achievable? Because i think I've been hitting a dead end for awhile now and I need help desperately. My thought process for this code was to tally up occurrences of each number occurring, and then (as this code was used for an instant runoff voting system) determine who has the highest 1 count and so on.

This is a portion of an instant runoff voting code and any information regarding if i am on the right track would be highly desirable

Comment: I think "nothing is impossible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
name_list = ["Bob" , "Henry" , "Jeff" , "Harry"]
number_list = ["1,4,2,3" , "4,3,1,2" , "3,2,4,1" , "1,2,3,4" , "4,3,2,1" , "1,2,4,3"] 
new_number_list = [list(map(int, i.split(","))) for i in number_list]
final_data = {a:{c:sum(d[i] == c for d in [e for e in new_number_list if e != a]) for c in new_number_list[i]} for i, a in enumerate(name_list)}
```

Output:

```
{'Bob': {1: 3, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2}, 'Jeff': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2}, 'Harry': {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1}, 'Henry': {1: 0, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1}}
```

Edit: to keep all values sorted, you can use this:

```
new_final_data = {a:sorted(b.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]) for a, b in final_data.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'Henry': [(1, 0), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)], 'Bob': [(1, 3), (2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2)], 'Harry': [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1)], 'Jeff': [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 2)]}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!
What i actually meant from my question was that in the new_final_data , i would want the instance of 1 occurring on position 0 in number_list to be tallied, then 2 occurring on position 0 in number_list... etc
This is then repeated for position 1 for number_list for the occurrence of 1 etc.

Comment: @H.Y so you want the number of times each number occurs at its current position in each number in `number_list`?

Comment: Yes!! That is exactly what i meant. If possible can you do it without any imported functions?

Comment: @H.Y it certainly can be done :) Just one question, however. In the first element of `number_list`, "1,4,2,3", two occurs at the second index. However, "4,3,2,1" also exists in the list, which contains 2 at the second index. However, you mark the notation as "2:0". Is there any reason for that?

Comment: The wording for my question is quite bad. sorry
So each element in number_list corresponds to name_list. So "Bob" is at position 0 in name_list. I want every number at position 0 for number_list to be tallied in a way. There are 3 1's at position 0 , 0 2'S AT POSITION 0 , 1 3's at position 0 and 2 4's at position 0

I am so sorry. I misread your previous question and I was just excited it could be done!

Comment: @H.Y No problem at all! I understand your question perfectly now! Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Hello again!! I put the code into python however, the output given is
{'Bob': {1: 3, 4: 2, 2: 0, 3: 1}, 'Henry': {4: 1, 3: 2, 1: 0, 2: 3}, 'Jeff': {3: 1, 2: 2, 4: 2, 1: 1}, 'Harry': {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1}}
which is not the same as yours, which goes from 1 to 5 but instead, descending order of occurrences. Is there a way to fix this? and have 1 to 5 each time? Thanks

Comment: @H.Y Unfortunately, the dictionary values will only remain sorted in Python2. However, I will write a solution that will keep the desired order; however, it will be a list of tuples rather than a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, I am not sure if you need a function since you didn't specify

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

# first lets create a list of dictionaries mapping each name to a number
maps = [dict(zip(name_list, chunk.split(','))) for chunk in number_list]

[{'Bob': '1', 'Harry': '3', 'Henry': '4', 'Jeff': '2'},
 {'Bob': '4', 'Harry': '2', 'Henry': '3', 'Jeff': '1'},
 {'Bob': '3', 'Harry': '1', 'Henry': '2', 'Jeff': '4'},
 {'Bob': '1', 'Harry': '4', 'Henry': '2', 'Jeff': '3'},
 {'Bob': '4', 'Harry': '1', 'Henry': '3', 'Jeff': '2'},
 {'Bob': '1', 'Harry': '3', 'Henry': '2', 'Jeff': '4'}]

for name in name_list:
    temp = Counter()
    # counter object where name is the key, value is another counter object
    temp.update({name: Counter(map(lambda x: x.get(name), maps))})
    num = len(temp.values()[0].keys())
    # create string to format
    fmt = '{} has {} occurences, ' * num
    print '{} - '.format(name) + fmt.format(*list(chain.from_iterable(temp.values()[0].items())))

Bob - 1 has 3 occurences, 3 has 1 occurences, 4 has 2 occurences, 
Henry - 3 has 2 occurences, 2 has 3 occurences, 4 has 1 occurences, 
Jeff - 1 has 1 occurences, 3 has 1 occurences, 2 has 2 occurences, 4 has 2 occurences, 
Harry - 1 has 2 occurences, 3 has 2 occurences, 2 has 1 occurences, 4 has 1 occurences,
```